# Wilcoxon test for mixed data

Tags: effect-size

I have gameplay data of 20 patients, some is following normal distribution and some is following non normal distribution, so I used Wilcoxon test to identify if there is significant change in speed in final gameplays from initial gameplays. What effect size measure should be used with this type of test? Can I use r, W or cliff delta for this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which measure of effect size you should use depends on your purposes.

Cliff's delta

$\Delta_c = \frac{\#(X_1 > X_2)-\#X_2>X_1}{n_1n_2}$ where # is the count function only accounts for which has more larger numbers, the size of the differences is ignored. One nice thing about Cliff's delta is that it ranges from -1 to +1.

Wilcoxon's W (which you are already using) measures whether there is a "location shift" but W itself is hard to interpret. It is

> The Wilcoxon statistic is returned as W = 13. This is NOT an estimate
> of the difference in medians. This is actually the number of times
> that a package weight from company B is less than a package weight
> from company A.

see [UVA](https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test).

But a better measure might be robust d. Essentially, this is d on Winsorized data. (That is, data where the X% most extreme values are replaced with the most extreme remaining values). You can select X, but I've seen 20% most often. I'm a fan of Winsorized means (and also trimmed means). Robust d is a sort of compromise between the usual Cohen's d and Cliff's d, which, hopefully, has some of the benefits of both.